# Django Looping Through Objects to Place Object Markers on Google Maps

Tags: javascript, python, django, loops, loopingselector

> I cannot figure out how to get checkmark pins to show up on google maps I have tried to loop this several different ways. When I take the function out the map shows back up. I am wondering if it is possible to do on Django in this manner. Thank you for any help.

```
{% extends 'maps/base.html' %}
{% block body %}

    <head>
    <style>
      #map {
        height: 50%;
        width:50%
      }
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      var map;
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 2,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(2.8,-187.3),
          mapTypeId: 'terrain'
        });
      // Loop through the results array and place a marker for each
      // set of coordinates.

           function loadMarkers(){
              {% for object in object_list %}
                  var point = new google.maps.LatLng({{object.latitude}},{{object.longitude}});
                  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  position: point,
                  map: map
              });
              {% endfor %} 


    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=APIKEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
```

Views:

```
class TestView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'maps/bbjecttest.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Location.objects.all()

    context_object_name = 'location'
```

Comment: I don't know if it is related to you issue, but using `object` as a variable name is not a good idea as `object` is a keyword in python.

Comment: Also, another suggestion, I'd generate the data of a javascript list using the template and assign to a JS variable, and then use pure javascript to iterate through the list and add to the map.

Comment: my object data is from my database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has some issues, first you are not closing the loadMarkers function.
You are also not calling the loadMarkers function anywhere.

I cannot run it now, but try it with the changes and let me know if it fixes for you:

```
{% extends 'maps/base.html' %}
{% block body %}

    <head>
    <style>
      #map {
        height: 50%;
        width:50%
      }
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      var map;
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 2,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(2.8,-187.3),
          mapTypeId: 'terrain'
        });
      // Loop through the results array and place a marker for each
      // set of coordinates.

           function loadMarkers(){
              {% for location in object_list %}
                  var point = new google.maps.LatLng({{location.latitude}},{{location.longitude}});
                  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  position: point,
                  map: map
              });
              {% endfor %} 
          }
          loadMarkers();

    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=APIKEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
```

---

To make it easier to debug, I'd do something like this to define the markers:

```
markers = []
{% for location in object_list %}
markers.push({long:{{location.longitude}}, lat:{{location.latitude}}});
{% endfor %}
```

And then use the javascript variable markers on your look when loadMarkers is called.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. It still does not show the marker, but the map does not disappear while the function is active. @luigibertaco

Comment: Can you check if the code for it is generating correctly when you inspect the page?

Comment: I was getting a init map error on my web browser, changed the code by modifying the position of sync defer, now it is showing no errors, but no map with pins is showing up. <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&callback=initMap" async defer>

Comment: IT JUST WORKED FOR A SECOND BUT WENT AWAY, is there any reason the browser wouldn't load it correctly?